# Hassle in Linkedlist in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Suppose I have 3 nodes already in the list (i.e. 10 , 20). And I want to insert 30. So wrote as below

```
struct node *p,*temp;
p=start;
temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->info=30;
temp->link=NULL;
while(p-link!=NULL) 
{
  p=p->link;
}
p->link=temp;
```

It worked perfectly until I do this: `while(p!=NULL)` rest is same..
Similarly in case of showing the node I wrote as follows

```
while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n",p->info);
        p=p->link;
    }
```

This also worked fine until I changed it to: `while(p->link!=NULL)`

I want to know what is happening why is not working? **Give me the reason why we are using while(p!=NULL) in case of showing the all the data and while(p->link!=NULL) in case of inserting any node?**

Comment: `while(p-link!=NULL;` ==> `while(p->link!=NULL)`.

Comment: `p->link!=NULL` check if `p->link` is a null pointer. `p!=NULL` checks if `p` is a null pointer. Not the same in the least.

Comment: After running through the  `while (p != NULL)` loop, `p` is `NULL`, which means that you cannot dereference it with `*p` or `p->link`.

Comment: This was just to shorten my program and point out the main problem..If I add the whole function it would look too messy and difficult to point the problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You do not show when exactly you want to do the `while(p!=NULL)`

Comment: "`p->link!=NULL` and `p!=NULL` aren't they both same?" --> No.  Consider what happens when `p==NULL`.  `p->link` attempts to de-reference a `NULL` pointer, that is _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Comment: why we are using while(p!=NULL) in case of showing the all the data and while(p-link!=NULL) in case of inserting any node?

Comment: As mch pointed out above, there's a typo in `while(p-link!=NULL)`. Have you taken care of that?

Comment: My bad Corrected it _babon

Comment: @SUVAMROY With showing all the data, code needs to get to the end of the list which is the NULL pointer.  To insert, code needs to stop just before the end.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is because `p->link=temp;` makes no sense if you're intentionally running `p` through a loop until `p` is NULL. Thereafter, `p->link=temp;` would be dereferencing a null pointer. The purpose of running only until `p->link` is NULL is to find the last node in the list (the one whose `next` is NULL), thereby having something on which to hang the new node (which becomes the last one in the list once hung). That said, this insert-code as-shown will puke horribly unless the list has at least one node already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the first `while` loop, you've got something like this. Two nodes (not three as you state) in a linked-list, pointed to by `start` and a new node, pointed to by `temp`:

```
start-->+---------+  +-->+---------+      +---------+<--temp
        |info:10  |  |   |info:20  |      |info:30  |
        |link:xxxx|--+   |link:NULL|      |link:NULL|
        +---------+      +---------+      +---------+
```

To add the new node to the end of the list, you need to advance `p` from the first node (pointed to by `start`) until `p` points at the node whose `link` is `NULL` (i.e., until `p->link!=NULL` fails to be true):

```
start-->+---------+  +-->+---------+      +---------+<--temp
        |info:10  |  |   |info:20  |      |info:30  |
        |link:xxxx|--+   |link:NULL|      |link:NULL|
        +---------+      +---------+      +---------+
                            ^
                            |
                         p -+
```

Once you have found the last node, you then "plumb" in your new node to get a three-element list:

```
start-->+---------+  +-->+---------+  +-->+---------+
        |info:10  |  |   |info:20  |  |   |info:30  |
        |link:xxxx|--+   |link:yyyy|--+   |link:NULL|
        +---------+      +---------+      +---------+
```

However, when you're *printing* all of the nodes, you start `p` at the first node (i.e. `start`) and print the details of every node until `p` has been set to `NULL` (i.e. `p!=NULL` fails to be true). If you stopped when `p->link` was `NULL`, you would not have printed the last node.

Comment: but when I say p->link!=null isn't p is at last node? as the last node's link is null..

Comment: Yes. `p` will be pointing at the last entry of the original list  (info=20; middle diagram). You then set `p->link=temp` to add the new node on to the end of the list (bottom diagram).

Comment: **So as p->link!=null also can reach upto the last node then why can't I use it for showing all the nodes?**  your answer was really very impressive. please answer this last question and I'm all set.

Comment: Because in the print-loop, when `p->link!=NULL` becomes true _you haven't yet printed_ the value for the node pointed to by `p`. Step through with a debugger (or a pencil and a bit of paper with boxes like above) and you will see this.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list, in `C` is a struct that contains data and a pointer to the next element (and maybe a pointer to the previous element, but that doesn't seem to be your case). It would be something like this:

```
struct node {
    int data; //could be any type
    struct node *next;
};
```

To insert elements in the end of the list, you need to go to the end of it - when there is no next element. To do that, you check `node->next == NULL`. Then you make `node->next = new_node`

To find an element in the list, you need to loop for all elements until you find it. If the element doesn't exists in the list, you need to prevent the user from accessing an invalid element, so you test `node == NULL` to finish the loop safely. This case is also applicable if you want to just print all data in the list - you need to reach all elements, the test would be the same (if you were testing `node->next == NULL`, you would skip the last element).